# Trouble defining foreign keys (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Working on an introduction to databases class assignment and running into trouble on a few foreign key. I've done a few foreign keys but every now and then I get stumped and can't figure out why it doesn't work.

This example is a university database and I have section

```
describe section;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| course_id    | varchar(7)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| sec_id       | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| semester     | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| year         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| building     | varchar(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| room_no      | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time_slot_id | varchar(5)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm trying to make a takes database and am able to make the foreign key for `ID` and `course_id`, but any other one I try doesn't work

```
create table takes(
  ID int, 
  course_id varchar(7), 
  sec_id varchar(10), 
  semester varchar(10), 
  year int, 
  grade int, 
  primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year), 
  foreign key (ID) references student(ID)
    on delete cascade on update cascade, 
  foreign key (course_id) references section(course_id) 
    on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine = innodb;
```

Up until this point it works.
If I try and add this, it give me `errno: 150`

```
foreign key (sec_id) 
  references section(sec_id) 
  on delete cascade on update cascade
```

Any help is appreciated. I think I might be missing something fundamental about foreign keys since it worked for `course_id` but not for `sec_id`, which seem to be completely the same?

Comment: After you see the `errno: 150`, run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. It contains information on why it failed on your new foreign key addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. Data types, including unsigned, are not matching.
2. Parent field is not indexed.

If the datatypes are matching, perhaps you have not defined an index on the parent column on which you wanted to define a foreign key relation. Please check if the column `sec_id` in table `section` has any indexes defined.

***Refer to***:

- [MySQL: InnoDB Error Codes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-error-codes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` of both the fields is same i.e, `takes(sec_id)` and `section(sec_id)`

Please refer to this check list : http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/

Comment: It seems as if they are both the same. For sec_id the collation is latin1_swedish_ci and for year it is NULL.

Comment: what is the engine for the 'section' table ?
Please check the link in answer.