# Error 1215 MySQL (Error Code: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint)

Tags: mysql, database

good morning. I've a problem with a database I'm designing. I have 5 tables and one is many to many relation. It table has multiple foreign key from the others tables. I create the database with MySQL Worckbecnh and when it's creating the table "Partido" it gives me an error 1215 with the foreign keys. I was looking for attributes with differents types, primary keys that doesn't defined but I think that I don't find nothing wrong in my code
I put here the code for yoy can help me.
Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE PABELLON (
    Codigo_pabellon INT NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30),
    Codigo_localidad INT(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (Codigo_pabellon),
    FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_localidad)
        REFERENCES LOCALIDAD (Codigo_localidad)
);

CREATE TABLE JORNADA (
    Codigo_jornada INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Numero INT(2),
    Codigo_Competicion INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Codigo_jornada)
);
CREATE TABLE EQUIPO (
    NIF VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30),
    Direccion VARCHAR(20),
    Telefono VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (NIF)
);
CREATE TABLE EQUIPO_ARBITRAL (
    DNI VARCHAR(9),
    Licencia INT(3),
    Nombre VARCHAR(20),
    Apellidos VARCHAR(20),
    Email VARCHAR(20),
    Telefono INT(9),
    Cuenta INT(20),
    Cod_localidad INT(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (DNI)
);
CREATE TABLE PARTIDO (
    Codigo_Partido INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EquipoA VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    EquipoB VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Fecha DATE,
    Hora TIME,
    Codigo_Pabellon INT NOT NULL,
    Codigo_jornada INT,
    ArbPrin VARCHAR(9),
    ArbAux VARCHAR(9),
    Anotador VARCHAR(9),
    Crono VARCHAR(9),
    Op24 VARCHAR(9),
    FOREIGN KEY (EquipoA , EquipoB)
        REFERENCES EQUIPO (NIF , NIF),
    FOREIGN KEY (ArbPrin , ArbAux , Anotador , Crono , Op24)
        REFERENCES EQUIPO_ARBITRAL (DNI , DNI , DNI , DNI , DNI),
    FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_Pabellon)
        REFERENCES PABELLON (Codigo_Pabellon),
    FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_jornada)
        REFERENCES JORNADA (Codigo_Jornada)
);
```

Comment: Could you pleas post the whole error message?

Comment: Please run `show engine innodb status` to find out the actual error message.

Comment: I Edit the post with the error message

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188061/trouble-defining-foreign-keys-mysql/22188109#22188109

Comment: LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2014-03-06 11:25:45 1534 Error in foreign key constraint of table gestion/partido:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I do not understand what your want to achieve by the multi column FKs?

Why do you add an FK like

```
FOREIGN KEY (EquipoA , EquipoB)
    REFERENCES EQUIPO (NIF , NIF),
```

over two columns?
These columns are independent from each other, besides they reference the same table. Therefore you should define two FKs like

```
FOREIGN KEY (EquipoA)
    REFERENCES EQUIPO (NIF),
FOREIGN KEY (EquipoB)
    REFERENCES EQUIPO (NIF)
```

You most likely want to change this accordingly in all FK definitions, which reference one column in the referenced table multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: With the last you say now I can create that table. Thank you very much.